# AWS error: Invalid operation: table name "?" specified more than once;

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server-2012, amazon-redshift

the below code works very well in SQL Server 2012, But when I use it in AWS amazon web service will give me a error "Amazon Invalid operation: table name "#t" specified more than once;"

```
CREATE TABLE #t (store_id varchar(20),city varchar(20),[state] varchar(20));
INSERT INTO #t VALUES
('22', 'new', 'NY'),
('22', null, null),
('22', null, null),
('33', null, null),
('33', 'LA', 'CA')
;

SELECT DISTINCT store_id, city, [state] 
INTO #unique
FROM #t WHERE city IS NOT NULL;
;

UPDATE #t
SET city = #unique.city, [state] = #unique.[state]
FROM #unique
INNER JOIN #t
ON #unique.store_id = #t.store_id
WHERE #t.city IS NULL
```

Does anyone know why and modify my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
UPDATE #t
SET city = #unique.city, [state] = #unique.[state]
FROM #unique
WHERE #unique.store_id = #t.store_id
AND #t.city IS NULL
```

Redshift does not need target table in `FROM` clause but in case if you need to specify it you need to alias it.

```
UPDATE #t
SET city = #unique.city, [state] = #unique.[state]
FROM #unique
JOIN #t t1
ON #unique.store_id = t1.store_id
WHERE t1.city IS NULL
```

From documentation

`If you need to include the target table of the UPDATE statement in the list, use an alias.`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html

Comment: I just don't know why AWS doesn't need a JOIN

Comment: in Redshift JOIN for target is optional using UPDATE, you can also join the target table, updated my answer with more info